# multi-threaded script hangs at the end

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Hello:  I am trying to get this script to work.  Sometimes depending on the number of users (the example below shows 3 but that can be easily increased), the script does not exit.  All the jobs are done but the script just hangs without exiting.  I think my approach to existing from the `while True` in `worker` is the problem, but I do not know of an alternative.  Any ideas?

```
import datetime, logging, os.path, queue, random, threading, time

script = os.path.basename(__file__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)-4s %(thread)6s  %(message)s", datefmt="%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    filename="%s_%s.log"%(script[:script.find(".")],datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")))

class User(object):

    def __init__(self, id, ndelay, mind, maxd):
        self.id = id
        self.numdelay = ndelay #number of delays
        self.mind = mind       #min delay
        self.maxd = maxd       #max delay
        self.currdelaynum = 0  #index for next delay

    def hasDelay(self):
        if self.currdelaynum >= 0 and self.currdelaynum < self.numdelay:
            return True

    def runNextDelay(self):
        delay = round(self.mind + random.random()*(self.maxd - self.mind))
        logging.info("%s beg (delay=%d)"%(self.id,delay))
        time.sleep(delay)
        logging.info("%s end"%self.id)            
        self.currdelaynum += 1


def worker(unext,udone):
    while True:
        if unext.qsize() > 0:
            m = unext.get()
            users_all[m].runNextDelay()
            if users_all[m].hasDelay():
                unext.put(m)
            else:
                udone.put(m)
        else:
            if udone.qsize() >= len(users_all):
                break


if __name__=='__main__':
    random.seed(10)

    #global users_all
    users_all = list()
    users_all.append(User("aa",2,3,9))
    users_all.append(User("bb",3,2,4))
    users_all.append(User("cc",1,4,5))

    users_next = queue.Queue()
    users_done = queue.Queue()
    for n in range(len(users_all)):
        users_next.put(n)

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(users_next,users_done)) for n in range(2)]
    for t in threads: t.start()
    for t in threads: t.join()
```

Most multithreaded python examples have a queue of jobs which are known upfront.  I am writing a script which tests the response times for queries running in parallel on a database.  To make the above example self-contained, I have replace the ODBC query part of it with `sleep`.  I would also appreciate any comments for a better implementation.

**Updated version based on comments**

```
def worker(unext):
    while True:
        try:
            m = unext.get_nowait()
            users_all[m].runNextDelay()
            if users_all[m].hasDelay():
                unext.put(m)
        except queue.Empty:
            break
```

Comment: Your access to the queues are unsynchronized, which will produce race conditions. In particular, you call `get()` based on a previous call to `qsize()` without a lock. Try calling `get()` optimistically and catching `Full` or `Empty` exceptions.

Comment: Isn't that exception only thrown if `get(block=False)` or `get_nowait()`.  Do I not need the block=True here?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the logic you're using here. What is `hasDelay` actually simulating in relation to a DB query? It's strange to take a work item off the queue, start to process it, then change your mind and put it back.

Comment: @dano I have `hasQuery` and `runNextQuery` in my DB script.  I replaced them with `Delay` to get a self-contained script. Here is the original problem: (i) each user has queries, (ii) a fixed number of queries can be run in parallel on the DB at any point in time. The queries must be run round-robin meaning query 1 for all users must fired before going to query 2. Queries for a given user cannot be run in parallel even if all the other jobs are completed...they have to be run sequentially.  In the code, I am taking the user out of the FIFO queue and putting back to get the round-robin effect.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by univerio, there are race conditions.  In general, when working with objects that are shared between multiple threads ask yourself the question, what would happen if my thread were interrupted at this point and another thread were allowed to run?  The case outlined by univerio is that the `qsize()` call may return non-zero in thread A, thread B then runs and pulls an item off the same queue.  By the time the thread A runs again to perform the `get()` the assumption that there is an item in the queue is wrong, and `get()` may block.

Here's some untested code which may be used to guide your final implementation:

```
def worker(unext, udone):
    while True:
        try:
            m = unext.get_nowait()
            users_all[m].runNextDelay()
            if users_all[m].hasDelay():
                unext.put(m)
            else:
                udone.put(m)
        except queue.Queue.Empty:
            if udone.qsize() >= len(users_all):
                break
```

This is still not an ideal implementation since when `unext` queue is empty but other threads have not finished processing, the while loop will be spinning furiously in all of the threads, waiting for the last thread to finish.

It may be better to have the threads simply do their work and exit when there is no more work left, and have the main thread wait for the `udone.qsize() >= len(users_all)` condition to become true.

Comment: You could avoid excessive CPU usage from spinning while loops by use `get(timeout=0.5)` (or some similar small value) rather than `get_nowait`.

Comment: I have updated `worker` at the end of orig post.  Based on the business problem, if a thread sees that the queue is empty, that thread can be exited.  There are enough threads remaining to handle the other users, since jobs for a given user have to be run sequentially.  This overcomes the spinning while loop issue and race conditions due to unsync queues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of the multithreaded code.  Changes:

1) threads have proper names ("thread-1"), which are included in logs

2) queues hold User instances, not indexes into global array

3) threads stop themselves if they get a None in the queue.  Init code `put()`s a number of Users into the input queue, then adds one None per thread on the end, so each thread will be signalled to exit.

4) workers log when they start and stop; User objects are directly printable.

### source

```
import datetime, logging, os.path, random, sys, threading, time
import Queue as queue

script = os.path.basename(__file__)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format="%(asctime)-4s %(threadName)s  %(message)s", datefmt="%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    stream=sys.stderr,
    # filename="%s_%s.log"%(script[:script.find(".")],datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")))
)

class User(object):

    def __init__(self, id, ndelay, mind, maxd):
        self.id = id
        self.numdelay = ndelay #number of delays
        self.mind = mind       #min delay
        self.maxd = maxd       #max delay
        self.currdelaynum = 0  #index for next delay

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: id={}>'.format(self.id)

    def hasDelay(self):
        return (
            self.currdelaynum >= 0 
            and self.currdelaynum < self.numdelay
        )

    def runNextDelay(self):
        delay = round(self.mind + random.random()*(self.maxd - self.mind))
        logging.info("%s beg (delay=%d)", self.id, delay)
        time.sleep(delay)
        logging.info("%s end", self.id)
        self.currdelaynum += 1


def worker(unext, udone):
    logging.info('start')
    for user in iter(unext.get, None):
        while True:
            user.runNextDelay()
            if not user.hasDelay():
                break
            logging.debug('%s: reloop', user)
        udone.put(user)
    logging.info('done')


if __name__=='__main__':
    random.seed(10)

    users_all = list()
    users_all.append(User("aa",2,3,9))
    users_all.append(User("bb",3,2,4))
    users_all.append(User("cc",1,4,5))

    users_next = queue.Queue()
    users_done = queue.Queue()
    for user in users_all:
        users_next.put(user)

    # flag each thread to exit at end
    num_threads = 2
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        users_next.put(None)

    threads = [
        threading.Thread(
            target=worker, 
            args=(users_next,users_done),
            name='thread-{}'.format(n),
        )
        for n in range(num_threads)
    ]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

### output

```
08-19 12:29:29 thread-0  start
08-19 12:29:29 thread-0  aa beg (delay=6)
08-19 12:29:29 thread-1  start
08-19 12:29:29 thread-1  bb beg (delay=3)
08-19 12:29:32 thread-1  bb end
08-19 12:29:32 thread-1  <User: id=bb>: reloop
08-19 12:29:32 thread-1  bb beg (delay=3)
08-19 12:29:35 thread-0  aa end
08-19 12:29:35 thread-0  <User: id=aa>: reloop
08-19 12:29:35 thread-0  aa beg (delay=4)
08-19 12:29:35 thread-1  bb end
08-19 12:29:35 thread-1  <User: id=bb>: reloop
08-19 12:29:35 thread-1  bb beg (delay=4)
08-19 12:29:39 thread-1  bb end
08-19 12:29:39 thread-0  aa end
08-19 12:29:39 thread-0  cc beg (delay=5)
08-19 12:29:39 thread-1  done
08-19 12:29:44 thread-0  cc end
08-19 12:29:44 thread-0  done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my job queue. My solution was, (sort of mentioned above) to call the get() function with a time-out of 0:

```
def run(self):
    while not self._stopevent.isSet():
        try:
            self._execute_job_function()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass    #make sure the application doesn't crash when the jobqueue is empty

def _execute_job_function(self):
    job = self._job_list.get(False, 0)  #calling get function with time-out = 0 to prevent hanging

    print("Executing job: {0}".format(job))
    self._results_queue.put("{0} - Done".format(job))
    self._job_list.task_done()
```

I hope this helps you.